# Delegation pattern, fancy name for interface design in OOP?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am a new comer to iOS from a C# / Java background. I've reading articles discussing the delegation pattern and how important it is. Once I started working with it I noticed it really is just designing interfaces and passing data around using the methods defined. Is that statement true? for iOS gurus who know .net or java, can I say that the delegation pattern is just interface design, and using the methods to pass data around between classes that implement that interface? or is the dynamic nature of objective C making me overlook some other powerful aspect ?

Comment: I am not entirely sure to be honest but here is a similar question asked the other way around. It may help a little bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209943/java-equivalent-of-cocoa-delegates-objective-c-informal-protocols

Comment: "Delegation" in Objective-C is, indeed, a rather mundane concept that seems to be the subject of considerable awe by those who consider it a special feature.  An Objective-C "protocol" is virtually identical to a Java "interface", eg, and Java has similar API features in their GUI interfaces, using different terminology.

Answer (score 3):

Delegation is different from interface design.

An interface in Java and C# is a collection of method declarations.  An interface is a kind of class (ie a type), which other classes may implement.  If a class implements an interface, that means it implements all of the methods declared by the interface.

The value of programming using interfaces is that you can create methods that accept objects that implement that interface without sharing a concrete class hierarchy.

A typical problem in object-oriented programming that arises is how to define an operation in terms of some other operations in a completely abstract way, relying only on some simple property of an object.  For example, you might like to implement a sorting algortihm that can work on any object that provides a compareTo method that compares two objects to see which order they go in.  Without interfaces, you can only write a sorting algorithm that works on all object types descended from a common superclass.  With interfaces, it is enough for each class that wants to be able to be sortable to implement the `Sortable` interface which declares the single method `compareTo` (say).

Interfaces can be used in many other ways, but at base what they provide is a more flexible style of programming based on a "contract".

Delegation refers to something more specific. Delegation helps when you need to provide a class that is a variant of an existing class (or set of classes) without subclassing. With delegation (aka the delegation pattern), you create a new class that holds an instance of the existing class (the delegate), and implements most of its methods by simply calling the delegate (it delegates).  A typical example is a caching implementation of a service.  The original service goes off and fetches some data (lets say it has a `fetch` method), and this may be expensive.  So we'd like to cache this.  A delegate would simply store the original service, and a cache: then when you call its `fetch` method, it checks the cache, and only if the cache misses does it call the delegate's `fetch`.  As long as the caching implementation implements the same interface as the delegate, it can be used in its place.

So there is some commonality with the idea of interfaces in the sense that delegation provides a mechanism of programming that is outside a strict class hierarchy, and it is (largely) made possible by the use of interfaces, but there are many other uses of interfaces as well.

Comment: Ok so this is a good, but I disagree with some statements here, in delegation the delegate class which needs to conform to a protocol is kind of doing the same as subclassing ( not talking about optional methods here). in the sense in C# a class implements an interface , in Objective C a delegate class conforms to a protocol.

Comment: I know multiple inheritance is achieved through interfaces in java C# and that's a difference, but for a non academic benefit and a real world usage they both still are implemented the same way. in Objective C you declare a protocl, you say what methods are in it, and the delegate class conforms to it, in OO (C#, JAVA ) you declare an interface ( a contract ) that all class implementing this inteface need to implement all methods in the same signature as defined in this interface.

Comment: An Objective-C protocol and a Java interface are virtually identical in function.  Neither one has anything really to do with delegate patterns, other than enabling them without the need for careful subclassing.

Comment: Java has concepts virtually identical to "delegates", but I'm not recalling the terminology right now.  I'm thinking they may be called "event handlers".